# Why do some github sources doesn't open simulator?

Tags: iphone, github

I Know this is a dumb question but i have to ask.

I have downloaded a wrapper class from github ( https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/iPhoneContacts) and when i run it, it doesn't open simulator.

Why so? because it doesn't have info.plist or wrapper class means we have to use them in our projects?

thanks

Comment: I think it is just an `lib`, not a `demo`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't open the simulator because it is not an application. It is a library (bunch of classes) that you can use in your own applications.